# Sharepoint Workflow Condtions

Tags: sharepoint-2013

I am new to sharepoint and am following tutorials to figure it all out. But I came a crossed an issue that googling hasn't helped with.

In the tutorial for workflows it mentions that I need to use the condition: **If Current item field equals value**. It is not there. I see all the other options that should be there but not that one. I have tried remaking the workflow, the list everything but I can't get that option to show up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type current and then press enter it will give the If statement required.